# Check if Azure Queue exists using REST proxy (PHP)

Tags: php, azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-queues

I'm trying to interact with an Azure Queue using a REST proxy courtesy of the ***[Windows Azure SDK for PHP](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-php)***. Whilst there are plenty of code samples ***[here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/Documentation/Articles/storage-php-how-to-use-queues/)***, I want to check whether a queue exists so that I can create it if necessary, before adding a message to it.

```
try {
  // setup connection string for accessing queue storage
  $connectionString = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=' . PROTOCOL . ';AccountName=' . ACCOUNT_NAME . ';AccountKey=' . ACCOUNT_KEY;

  // create queue REST proxy
  $queueRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createQueueService($connectionString);

  // create message
  $queueRestProxy->createMessage(QUEUE_NAME, 'Hello World!');

} catch(ServiceException $e){
  // Handle exception based on error codes and messages.
  // Error codes and messages are here: 
  // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179446.aspx
  $code = $e->getCode();
  $error_message = $e->getMessage();
  echo $code.": ".$error_message."<br />";
}
```

Creating a queue is as simple as this...

```
$queueRestProxy->createQueue(QUEUE_NAME);
```

Should I simply include the queue creation code prior to creating a message or is there a more efficient way to ascertain whether the queue exists before interacting with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've posted an answer below for completeness and to make it easy for people to see the answer at a glance.

> Should I simply include the queue creation code prior to creating a
>   message or is there a more efficient way to ascertain whether the
>   queue exists before interacting with it?

There are two ways to approach this...

1. Include the `createQueue` statement prior to creating a message, but wrap this statement in a `try-catch` block as directed by [Guarav Mantri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21542300/2047725) i.e. ignore 409 errors, but throw an exception for any other types of error.

   For information, when you include a `createQueue` statement prior to creating a message...

   - if a queue of the same name already exists ***and*** the metadata
     associated with the existing queue ***is*** the same as that passed to the
     `createQueue` statement then the queue will not be created and the
     Queue REST Proxy will internally receive a **204** (No Content) status code, but this
     response code is not made available to the programmer. So,
     essentially, the `createQueue` statement doesn't cause an
     error/exception to be raised in this scenario.
   - if a queue of the same name already exists ***and*** the metadata
     associated with the existing queue ***isn't*** the same as that passed
     to the `createQueue` statement then the queue will not be created and
     the Queue REST Proxy will receive a **409** (Conflict) status code and will raise an
     exception which allows the programmer to access this response code and the associated `QueueAlreadyExists` message.

   Source: [Create Queue (REST API)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179342.aspx) - see Remarks section
2. Create a `queueExists` function and call it to decide whether or not queue creation is necessary. Here is one way to implement such a function...

   ```
   public function queueExists($queueRestProxy, $queueName) {
     $result = FALSE;
     $listQueuesResult = $queueRestProxy->listQueues();
     $queues = $listQueuesResult->getQueues();
     foreach($queues as $queue) {
       if ($queue->getName() === $queueName) {
         $result = TRUE;
         break;
       }
     }
     return $result;        
   }
   ```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

Normally in other Windows Azure SDKs I have seen methods like `createQueueIfNotExists` and I'm surprised that this method is missing from PHP SDK. Basically the way this function works is that it tries to create a queue. If the queue by the same name exists in storage, storage service throws a `Conflict (409)` error.

Since this function is not there, you could do the same i.e. try to create the queue inside its own try/catch block and check the error code. If the error code is 409, you continue otherwise you rethrow the exception. Something like the code below:

```
try {
  // setup connection string for accessing queue storage
  $connectionString = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=' . PROTOCOL . ';AccountName=' . ACCOUNT_NAME . ';AccountKey=' . ACCOUNT_KEY;
    // create queue REST proxy
        $queueRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createQueueService($connectionString);
  try {
    // now try to create the queue.
$queueRestProxy->createQueue(QUEUE_NAME);
  } catch(ServiceException $e){
    $code = $e->getCode();
    //Now check if the $code is 409 - Conflict. If the error code is indeed 409, you continue otherwise throw the error
  }
  // create message
  $queueRestProxy->createMessage(QUEUE_NAME, 'Hello World!');

} catch(ServiceException $e){
  // Handle exception based on error codes and messages.
  // Error codes and messages are here: 
  // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179446.aspx
  $code = $e->getCode();
  $error_message = $e->getMessage();
  echo $code.": ".$error_message."<br />";
}
```

P.S. I have not tried to execute the code, so it may throw errors. This is just to give you an idea.

Comment: @Guarav - thanks for your reply. After some testing, it appears that multiple consecutive calls to createQueue(QUEUE_NAME) do not cause a ServiceException to be thrown, so it seems that the Azure internals handle this silently. Perhaps that's why they don't publish createQueueIfNotExists nor queueExists methods in the SDK.

Comment: I don't think so. Furthermore all other SDKs have this function. See here for .Net: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueue.createifnotexists.aspx. All SDKs are wrapper over REST API so I don't think this is the reason.

Comment: Admittedly, my observation doesn't agree with the "Remarks" section on the Create Queue REST API page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179342.aspx) which is in line with your answer i.e. 409 returned if queue exists with non-matching metadata, 204 returned if queue exists with matching metadata. However, I'm not seeing the reality of these responses codes as no exception is thrown.

Comment: Interestingly, there's a unit test called "testCreateQueueWithExistingQueue" which calls createQueue($queueName) twice and expects that only 1 queue is created (without any exception handling) - see https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-php/blob/61d4e12495358491f62cc5bd8716335b0b313488/tests/unit/WindowsAzure/Queue/QueueRestProxyTest.php

Comment: I see. Thanks for the documentation link and you're right (learnt something new today :)). So if you try to create a queue with a name matching with existing queue and metadata is not different, status code returned is 204 which is not really an exception situation thus you will not get the error. I think anytime storage service sends a status code which is greater than or equal to 400, you will get service exception. Otherwise no exception will be raised.

Comment: I tested creating "queue1" with metadata, then creating "queue1" without metadata and a ServiceException (error code 409) was raised. I then tried creating "queue1" with metadata matching the 1st creation and no ServiceException was raised (presumably a 204 code was returned but I can't see a way to access it via the Queue REST Proxy).

Comment: I could not find anything in the SDK which would allow me to track response headers. I guess you could try tracing the request/response through a tool like Fiddler. Or you could just go with blind trust that the service is returning 204 status code :).

Comment: Me neither! As you say, it's not really necessary to know about the 204 status code anyway, so "blind trust" is fine! Many thanks for your input.